# Which structure to use for a Confusion Matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix

I have the following problem. I need to build a confusion matrix (also know as a contingency table or an error matrix).

Let's say I have:

```
Reference:  a b c d e f g    
Hypothesis: a p c x e m g

Reference:  c e g f z     
Hypothesis: e e g p z
```

and many more cases like that. The confusion matrix serves to show where the most problems are, on the vertical axis you would have all of the reference characters and on the horizontal axis you would have all hypotheses and their percentages.

A few visual examples here: [EXAMPLE](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/llog/DogTable4.gif)

My question is, which data structure should I use? I was thinking about two dimensional lists, but it seems that isn't the best solution. I basically need for each reference example a list of hypotheses and how often they occur.

I dont know how many different references I will have, so the creation needs to be dynamic.

Does anyone have any idea? I have read little about hashmap (although I dont yet understand it deeply). Should I use one of those?

Comment: Sounds like you want `Map<Reference,Map<Hypothesis,Likelihood>>`. A `HashMap` would be fine as you do not need a specific ordering.

Comment: Thanks I will check that, the thing is that Iam very new to Java. The order shouldnt be important.

Comment: If you wanted to also go from Hypothesis to References in O(1), this would no longer suffice, and you'd need an implementation that provides keyed access to both axes not just one. That can be implemented by managing two maps.